# Wordpress Multisite installation on subdomains without using root domain?

Tags: php, subdomain, wordpress

I have a functional website that we'll call root.com and i would rather not install wordpress on it, considering i already have my own custom files on it.

I need my multisite installation to run on a network made up of 5 subdomains namely:

```
hub.root.com
a.root.com
b.root.com
c.root.com
d.root.com
```

My problem is that when i tried to install wordpress to hub.root.com as i intended to, so as to use multiste and create a network with the other subdomains;

i got

```
a.hub.root.com
```

instead of

```
a.root.com
```

and so on

An easy solution would be to install wordpress in the root.com directory instead of the hub.root.com directory, but that is not an option, as i should preferably not alter the root directory files or install a cms directly into the root directory.

Could anyone please tell me if there is a workaround to this problem? It seems so straightforward, but yet i've spent hours trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress installation options.

Answer (score 0):

To get a.root.com working, you will need to install WordPress on the root.com domain.

As you mentioned that there are some custom files you want to server on root.com domain, I would suggest to install WordPress using WordPress in different directory approach. It is explained in the below article of WordPress documentation site.

[Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

As mentioned in the Section "Using a pre-existing subdirectory install", you will need to only copy index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress instance to the root of the domain root.com.

Once WordPress is working properly, you can move ahead with MultiSite feature for other sub-domains.